# jqgrid problem:Where is the "filter" param?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Am curently looking at the jqgrid documentation on advanced search and specifically search_adv.php file that comes with it.

I have noted the following line of code

```
$searchstr = Strip($_REQUEST['filters']);
```

However when I look at the output on firebug of my jqgrid post I see

```
_search         true
nd              1270148130165
page            1
rows            10
searchField     income_types_desc
searchOper      eq
searchString    5
sidx            income_types_desc
sord            asc
```

Where on earth is the "filter" param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filter` param is used when you perform an advanced (`allowMultiple:true`) search. It ends up containing a JSON object, which looks something like this:

```
filters = 
    {"groupOp":"AND",
     "rules":[
       {"field":"invdate","op":"ge","data":"2007-10-06"},
       {"field":"invdate","op":"le","data":"2007-10-20"}, 
       {"field":"name","op":"bw","data":"Client 3"}
      ]
    }
```

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching

Comment: Thanks alot.It really took me time to figure this thing out